# Can we distance ourselves from friends and others in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, friendship

I'm a high schooler who is trying to practice the religion and learn more and more each passing day.

However, my friend group usually consists of 2 girls and one guy.
(I'm a guy btw)

Although I like the 2 girls to a certain  extent, I'm not fond of myself hanging out with them due to my religion. But this got me thinking: I don't wanna hang out with them anymore, nor do I want to hang out with anyone who I see as an obstacle for myself (e.g. rude jerks, people who distract me from me trying to achieve my goals, etc)

Is it Haram to distance myself from friends and be all by myself? I know it's hard but I don't know what to do

Comment: there are two questions here, one in the heading and one in the main text. if it is the question in the heading, what do you mean by 'others'??. please ask one direct question so that the community can be specific and accurate in answering your query.

Comment: Others means people in general, whether they're close or not

Comment: I don't think it is haram. As long as they are not your family then it is fine. From my experience studying at Islamic schools for years, I was taught to distance myself from female students  (girls).

Comment: You should focus your question on "Can we distance ourselves from friends in Islam?" as will make this "others" a too broad topic